# Question: prove that if a,b,c and d are integers such that a+b=c+d, then the matrix A=[ a b, c d] has integer eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra

Question: prove that if a,b,c and d are integers such that a+b=c+d, then the matrix A=[ a b, c d] 
 has integer eigenvalues.

Attempt at solution: So to find the eigenvalues of a 2x2 matrix we have to use det( λͅI - A) = 0

So my matrix would then be [ λͅ-a -b, -c λͅ-d] 
 and then to find the determinant the following calculation must be done ( λͅ-a)( λͅ-d)-(bc)

If this is then made equal to 0, then we can solve for the eigenvalues. 
 first I must multiply and expand the equation

so: λͅ^2 - d λͅ - a λͅ +ad -bc = 0

From here I have a couple of problems

1) I don't understand how to factor this and show that its root (the eigenvalues) will in fact be integers (non-fractional values) 
 2) how does the relation a+b= c+d come into this

I feel like I'm missing the key to this question, I would be grateful for any help 
 and btw this is elementary linear algebra

Additional Info: I have seen a version of this exact question where it says that I have to prove that the eigenvalues are integers namely λͅ1= a+b and λͅ2= a-c when I solve the eigenvalues out. although this isn't a part of my question above, it might hint to how I could find my solution. I'm not exactly sure :/

Comment: Can you guess one eigenvector? As a column...

Comment: Just solve the quadratic equation and use the equation a+b = c+d. You will see that the discriminant is a square number.

Comment: with this :  λͅ^2 - d λͅ - a λͅ +ad -bc = 0    how would I put it into the quadratic formula? I need something that is in the form of a^2+bx+c to put it into the quadratic equation.

Comment: Will Jagy - I'm not exactly sure what you mean by that

Comment: @stacy: What vector $v$ will produce $A v = \begin{bmatrix} a+b \\c+d \end{bmatrix}$?

Answer (score 2):

The characteristic equation is $\lambda^2 -(a+d) \lambda + ad-cb = 0$,
hence we know that the solutions are
$\lambda = {1 \over 2} (a+d  \pm \sqrt{(a+d)^2-4 (ad-cb)})$.

We know that $\sqrt{(a+d)^2-4 (ad-cb)}$ is either imaginary, an integer or
irrational.

One eigenvalue is straightforward to guess using the vector $(1,1)^T$. This
is an integer, hence we know that both eigenvalues are real (since they
occur in conjugate pairs otherwise). Since it is an integer, we know that
$\sqrt{(a+d)^2-4 (ad-cb)}$ is an integer.

Furthermore, the formula above shows that
the difference between the two pairs is $\sqrt{(a+d)^2-4 (ad-cb)}$, which is
an integer. Hence the other eigenvalue is an integer.

Comment: There is no need to guess anything here: $\sqrt{(a+d)^2-4 (ad-cb)} = \sqrt{(a-d)^2 + 4cb} = \sqrt{(c-b)^2+4cb} = \sqrt{(b+c)^2} = \pm(b+c)$.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: I prefer the suspense...

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: :-)!

Comment: @copper.hat  Thank you so much. That makes a lot of sense to me now how that was put into the quadratic equation.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp  thank you also. I must go strengthen my ability to use the quadratic equation